# Make Titanium Backup work across multiple user accounts

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, multi-user, titanium-backup

I'm using CyanogenMod 12.0. I have installed Titanium Backup in primary user account.  I have an another user. I tend to let the other user have apps like Facebook, WhatsApp, some games, etc., while letting the owner for maintenance of the device.

The owner has root access while the other user doesn't, so I can't use Titanium Backup as the other but I need to make backups of the other user's apps.  Titanium Backup only lists the apps installed under the primary user account.

So, how to make backup of apps installed in a secondary user account, using Titanium Backup?

### Note

I know there exists other backup options but I want to use Titanium Backup (one day or another I'll have to).

If there are other ways besides "using SuperSU instead" I'd appreciate it.

Comment: Can CM's root option not be enabled for secondary accounts?

Comment: @MatthewRead sorry But I didn't find anything like that in the settings, All what I found is Developer Options -> Root access where I can disable it completely or allow only ADB or allow only apps or both.